# Buildroot 2021.08.x on MacOS 10.15.6 gcc not installed error

Tags: macos, gcc, buildroot

Trying to build a very simple test image with Buildroot 2021.08.x on MacOS 10.15.6 and get an error that gcc is not installed:

```
z:buildroot User$ make
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
LLVM ERROR: IO failure on output stream: Broken pipe
/bin/sh: line 0: [: : integer expression expected
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

You must install 'gcc' on your build machine
make: *** [dependencies] Error 1
```

I installed and reinstalled gcc with brew. The installed version with brew is 11.2.0

```
z:~ User$ brew list --versions gcc
gcc 11.2.0
```

But the gcc --version output looks like this:

```
z:~ User $ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you should not use clang for buildroot compiler.

you have to make gcc command linked to where installed by homebrew.

Comment: Thanks for replying. We've moved on from BuildRoot and are using Yocto now. I appreciate the response though!